# return values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have python pandas data frame like this with 200k to 400k rows

```
Index value
  1     a
  2 
  3     v
  4
  5
  6    6077
  7
  8     h
```

and I want this dataframe value column to be filled all below rows with the specific value based on number of string values(like here in this table we have 1 number of string value).
I want my dataframe to be like this.

```
Index value
  1     a
  2     a 
  3     v
  4     v
  5     v
  6     v
  7     v
  8     h
```

Comment: So remove the numbers and fill using the last non null value?

Comment: have you tried something lke ```df[df['value']==""] = np.NaN``` and then 
```df.fillna(method='ffill')``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need repeat strings with length `1` you can use [`Series.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) by regex `[a-zA-Z]{1}` for check if strings with length `1`, replace not matched values to `NaN`s by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and last forward filling missing values by `ffill`:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].where(df['value'].str.match('^[a-zA-Z]{1}$', na=False)).ffill()
print (df)
   Index value
0      1     a
1      2     a
2      3     v
3      4     v
4      5     v
5      6     v
6      7     v
7      8     h
```

Another idea:

```
m1 = df['value'].str.len().eq(1)
m2 = df['value'].str.isalpha()
df['value'] = df['value'].where(m1 & m2).ffill()
```

Comment: If your intention is to treat values of two or more alpha characters as if they were empty strings, then you should be calling `fullmatch`.

Comment: @Booboo - My intension is treat strings with length 1

Comment: Then you need to use `fullmatch` or use a `$` anchor because `match('[a-zA-Z]{1}') applied against 'xyz' will return a hit against the first character.

Answer (score 0):

The `forward fill` method in `fillna` is exactly for this.
This should work for you:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: 1. You are assuming that there are `numpy.na` values in the series, but they are empty strings. 2. The value at index 6 is a number and should be treated as if it were an empty string. 3. Your call to `fillna` returns a new dataframe that is not assigned to anything. 4. Your call to `fillna` will operate on all the cells of the dataframe, which you do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd

df['value'].replace('\d+', pd.np.nan, regex=True).ffill()
```

---

```
0    a
1    a
2    v
3    v
4    v
5    v
6    v
7    h
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: 1. That will replace only the value at index 6,; the other values are empty strings and not `np.nan`. 2. The return from `ffill` returns a new dataframe which is not being assigned to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have removed all numbers, do this:

```
df[df['value']==""] = np.NaN
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Look at the original problem at index 6, which contains a number, which is to be treated as if it were an empty string and not propagated forward (look at the expected output). Also, your call to `fillna` returns a new dataframe which is not assigned to anything. Also, your call to `fillna` will operate on all the cells of the dataframe and I don't think you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that any value that is not an empty string or number should be forward filled, then the regular expression `r'^\d*$'` will match both an empty string or number. These values can be replaced by `np.nan` and then `ffill` can be called:

```
import numpy as np

df['value'].replace(r'^\d*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
df['value'].ffill(inplace=True)
```